# PostgreSQL: dynamically create result columns

Tags: postgresql

I want to "dynamically" create the result columns in a PostgreSQL query. I have these tables:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE users_id;
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('users_id'),
  name VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL
);

CREATE SEQUENCE quota_rules_id;
CREATE TABLE quota_rules (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('quota_rules_id'),
  user_id INT REFERENCES users(id),
  rule VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX user_id_index ON quota_rules(user_id);

INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('myname'); -- id=1
INSERT INTO quota_rules (user_id, rule) VALUES (1, 'a');
INSERT INTO quota_rules (user_id, rule) VALUES (1, 'b');
INSERT INTO quota_rules (user_id, rule) VALUES (1, 'c');
```

And want a query that returns this (1 row):

```
SELECT ............ user_id = 1;
name   | quota_rule | quota_rule2 | quota_rule3
myname | a          | b           | c
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the `crosstab` function of the [tablefunc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) module

Comment: Thank you! All the examples I've seen goes something like: SELECT * FROM crosstab('..') AS (field1, field2, field3); Is it possible to dynamically make the right side? Ex: If there were five rows in quota_rules, I'd end up with (name,quota_rule,quota_rule2,quota_rule3,quota_rule4,quota_rule5)?